# Untrusted Application Launcher in Coin

Tags: 18.04

I am having a problem after we installed the coin application in Ubuntu 18.04. I'm getting an error like this "The application Launcher "coinwrapper.desktop" has not been markedas trusted. If you do not know the source of this file, launching it may be unsafe" Is there any

Comment: this means if you are sure you trust the source of application.. you have to give permission to trust it.. after that the programme works as intended..

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to nobody special, desktop files can be trusted via command line: gio set Your_desktop_file.desktop "metadata::trusted" yes

NOTE:

You have to run this command with the same user as the owner of the desktop files
It only works if you run the command in the gnome shell (not via SSH)
To do this automatically at logon, you have to make a logon script what will execute an script, as this only run when Gnome is started. For example you can create an .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart/ what execute some shell script including the gio commands
Make sure nautilus-desktop is really started. You can create an while loop with a sleep 1 till nautilus-desktop run
Icon's will not refresh automatically. You can achieve this with pressing F5 on the desktop or restart nautilus in your autostart script. killall nautilus && nautilus-desktop & (the last & sign is to make sure the rest of your code will run. Otherwise it will stop the script there till you close nautilus-desktop process again)

sir almen